# How to change variable in a module?

Tags: python, inheritance, package

For a.py:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self,var = 0):
        self.var = var
    def p(self):
        print(self.var)
```

For b.py:

```
import a
a.var=2
o=a()
o.p()
```

What I want is: 2.
But it shows: 0.

When I import the module, `ta`, I want to use `add_all_ta_features` in this module, which use other class in this module. Meanwhile, I want to change the variable in other class, but  the result is still the same.
Could anyone help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: `var` is an *instance variable*, and yet you're expecting it to work like a *class variable*. Either you have to instantiate the class `a` in order to set its `var`, or make `var` a class variable so that you can set it on the base object itself rather than a particular instance.

Comment: To use it as an instance variable: `o=a()` then `o.var=2`. Then `o.p()` will work as expected.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks for the reply. Actually, the var is defined in the module, and I can not change the module. And I have to use another method in this module to generate the result, thus I can not create an instance. So are there any other way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Could you give some more details about the `ta` module that you mentioned at the bottom of the question? Can you provide details about its contents?

Answer (score 0):

For a.py:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self,var = 0):
        self.var = var
    def p(self):
        print(self.var)
```

For b.py

```
import a
ob=a.a(2)
## Or you can do
## ob=a.a()
## ob.var=2
p=ob.p()
```

In this case, your output will be 2, What exactly is happening that your class name and the python module name are the same. In here you have just imported the module, but when you create an object of any class you have to use the class name using the above method or by these methods.

```
## Method 2
from a import a
ob=a(2)
## Or you can do
## ob=a()
## ob.var=2
p=ob.p()
```

or

```
## Method 3
import a as obj
ob=obj.a(2)
## Or you can do
## ob=obj.a()
## ob.var=2
p=ob.p()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and initialise `a`

`b.py`:

```py
import a

an_a = a()
a.var = 23 #set whatever you want
print(a.var)
```